# Javascript return active link

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

Sorry I am quite novice to Javascript.

When a page has loaded, I would like to get the active link in a menu.

I can't compare the current url with the address the  points to (links trigger connection within the current page).

The idea is to loop through all the a tags (in a table) and check whether the state of the link is active.
An active link diplays differently by default, so I suppose that there is a way to get this info by querying the element properties.

For the moment I am working round it by checking whether the link diplays as a default active link

```
if (document.getElementById('MyTable').rows[i].style.fontWeight =="bold"){
    ..some code...
}
```

This obviously works, but if for some reason the boldness applied regardless of the link status this would fail, so I feel like it is not the most solid method.

I am looking for something like

```
if (document.getElementById('MyTable').rows[i].cells[0].childNodes[0].active == true){
    ..some code...
}
```

The childNodes[0] of the first column cell would be the a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're much better off doing this server side or alternately google 'body class CSS navigation'

And if you're triggering jumps within the same page just tack on #xyz at the end of the URL and you can compare that in JavaScript.

Comment: I am quite novice and I can't even picture what it would entail to do it server side. I probably should have mentioned that I am on sharepoint, and links are __doPostBack functions that connect to Data View Wep Parts. I don't understand why it is so hard to get the active link, since any browser does it out of the box and applies a specific formatting (bold text or whatever) to it. Judging from the many workarounds I have come accross googling it seems that there is no 'active' property that would return a boolean value if queried via Javascript, as I was hoping. I am surprised.

Answer (score 2):

we can achive this by using style class.check the below link for more details like how to set active and find the active link from java script.

[Active link in java script](http://www.cssnewbie.com/using-javascript-to-style-active-navigation-elements/)

Comment: As I said, I can't compare the current url with the address the links point to. I am on ASP.NET and the links trigger __doPostBack functions. But thanks anyway.